# Communicating from fragment back to main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been searching for solutions for a couple of days now, but am still scratching my. I have an activity that launches 3 fragements, each fragment being a section of a remote control. Thus there are many buttons on each fragment. What I need to do is to be able to get the information on which button was pushed back to the activity so it can do something with the information. I see that the listener/interface method is the right way, but all the examples I've found use a Listview,  where you only need to set the listener once. I have multiple onClick listeners for each button on the remote.

Here is how the fragement is declared:

```
public class RemoteFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = null;
    String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    if ( message.equals( "main") ) {
        v = createViewMain( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );
    }
    else if ( message.equals("control") ) {
        v = createViewControl( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );
    }
    else if ( message.equals("numeric") ) {
        v = createViewNumeric( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );
    }

    return v;
}

private View createViewMain (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remote_main, container, false);

    Button roomOffButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.room_off);
    roomOffButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OnButtonPushed( v);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Room Off pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    });

//....
}

@Override
public void onClickListener( View view ) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try{
        ((OnButtonPushedListener) activity).onButtonPushed(view);
    }catch (ClassCastException cce){

    }
}

public interface OnButtonPushedListener{
    public void onButtonPushed(View view);
}
```

I get an error on the declaration of onClickListener telling me I must override or implement a supertype method (which I thought I was doing). When I try and call onButtonPushed in the listener, it tells me that onButtonPushed(view) is undefined for the type View.OnClickListener (which I thought I was doing when I overrode it).

Back in the main activity, I've declared it

```
public class RemoteActivity extends FragmentActivity implements RemoteFragment.OnButtonPushedListener {
```

and have implemented the interface as so:

```
@Override
public void OnButtonPushed(View view ) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "in the interface ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

which is doesn't either. I'm sure I must be missing something simple....Am I?

Many thanks....

Comment: Please copy and paste the **exact** compiler errors. Paraphrasing often loses critical information which we need to help you.

Answer (score 1):

To call a method in an activity from a fragment do this:

((MyActivyt)getActivity()).myMethod();

Comment: This does work, but I'd like to understand how to implement the more general purpose interface method.

Comment: @user3508881 cast to the interface instead of `MyActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement method onClick() interface [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html):

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
```

Comment: That's what I'd prefer to do...implement an interface that is a more general purpose solution. But I'm not sure what to implement/override in the fragement and what to implement in the activity. The fragement has over 40 different buttons that use onClick to return different buttons presses. How do I generalize to a single method that all can use?